# How to replace HTML encoded characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a XML which I parse and place in HTML, dynamically when asked for.

It has some line feed `&#xa;` which I want to replace with `&#10;&#09;`, so it comes in proper readable format.
For some reason `&#xa;` is not creating a LineFeed.

```
var lput=$(xml).find('lput_info').attr('output');

lput=lput.ReplaceAll("&#xa;", "&#10;&#09;");

'<table class="jpanelTable" >'+
    '<tbody>'+              
    '<tr width="100%">'+
        '<th class="thPanel">Output</th>'+
        '<td class="tdPanel"><pre class="preWrap">'+lput+'</pre></td>'+
    '</tr>'+                
    '</tbody>'+
'</table>'
```

Using this function from [here](http://codes.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/75-String-ReplaceAll-function-in-JavaScript.aspx):

```
String.prototype.ReplaceAll = function(stringToFind,stringToReplace){
    var temp = this;
    var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
    while(index != -1){
        temp = temp.replace(stringToFind,stringToReplace);
        index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**Update**

```
.preWrap {
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: "Consolas",monospace;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align:left;
    background-color: #FCF7EC;
    overflow-x: auto; /* Use horizontal scroller if needed; for Firefox 2, not
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:5px 5px 3px 5px;
    white-space : normal; /* crucial for IE 6, maybe 7? */
}
```

Part of the xml input string:

```
"bpmz.a&#xa;/usr/lib/libdl.a(shr_64.o)&#xa;/usr/lib/libperfstat.a(shr_64.o)&#xa;/usr/lib/lib.a"
```

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question with that `ReplaceAll()` function? Your code seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/DRKSk/ so perhaps the input string doesn't contain quite what you think it does. What does `console.log(lput)` show you? Please be a bit clearer about what the problem is.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Somehow the input from xml is not displaying with proper lineFeeds. In `console.log` I cannot see the it either

Answer (score 1):

Some people might suggest a (jQuery) function that creates a temporary `div`, places the text in there, then gets the content of the `div`, to decode the string.

Although the implementation of it is simple, it is rather unsafe, since you'd pretty much be asking for users to put all kinds of html tags in the string.

[I'd suggest using these functions](http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode/)
([Requires a second function](http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table/))

These are safer than the `div` alternative.